# Understanding Javascript scope with modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am trying to understand how scope works with node modules. I have an IIFE to initialize a LinkedList, which uses Node object for each element.
*using IIFE to avoid polluting global scope*

After IIFE, where does the Node go? Is there any way I can access Node in require object i.e. test class?

### linkedList.js

```js
(function LinkedListInit() {
    module.exports = new LinkedList();

    function LinkedList() {
        this.head;
    }

    // LinkedList Node
    function Node(data, next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    LinkedList.prototype.insert = insert;

    function insert(data) {
        var curr = this.head,
            newNode = new Node(data);
            
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = newNode;
        } else {
            while (curr.next != null) {
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            curr.next = newNode;
        }
        return this;
    }
}());
```

### linkedListTest.js

```
var linkedList = require('../../js/ds/linkedList');
// Test cases for linkedList.insert(val); works fine.

// Can I access Node here?
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, any functions and variables defined in your ES6 module are module scoped, i.e. your IIFE is not necessary in this case. `Node` or `insert` will not be accessible from outside the module unless they are explicitly exported via `module.exports`.

---

With that in mind, unit tests won't be able to simply access the implementation details either. If you want to test `Node` separately, the cleanest way would likely to move it to a separate module and import it into `LinkedList`:

```
// Node.js
function Node(data, next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

module.exports = Node;


// LinkedList.js
var Node = require('./Node');

function LinkedList() {
    this.head;
}
LinkedList.prototype.insert = function(data) {
    var curr = this.head,
        newNode = new Node(data);

    if (this.head == null) {
        this.head = newNode;
    } else {
        while (curr.next != null) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        curr.next = newNode;
    }
    return this;
}

module.exports = LinkedList;


// NodeTest.js
var Node = require('./Node');

var node = new Node('foo');
// ...


// LinkedListTest.js
var LinkedList = require('./LinkedList');

var linkedList = new LinkedList();
linkedList.insert('foo');
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks @timo, you actually helped me in improving the way I use module.exports. I used to do module.exports = new LinkedList(). Now I think I was doing it wrong all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The only things accessible outside of the Node module are those added to the `module.exports` variable.

When you do

```
var x = require('./some/path');
```

x will be equal to the `module.exports` variable defined in `./some/path.js`.

Unless `Node` is somehow made explicitly available in your `module.exports` object, you cannot access it from outside the module file.

The typical way to define modules with an IIFE in Node is to do:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    //...a lot of code...
    return { 
      exportedValue1: somethingIWantToBeAvailable;
      exportedValue2: aDifferentThing;
      //... and so on ...
    };
})();
```

But you don't really need the IIFE. Unlike a browser environment, stuff only gets added to the global scope in node if you *explicitly* request that by saying

```
global.variable = something;
```

Otherwise, your variable is in **module-local** scope. As Node treats modules and files as being in one-to-one correspondence, this means any variables you create within a file are only accessible within that file - barring the use of `global` and `module.exports`.

Comment: Note that this answer is highly Node.js specific -- depending on your runtime and build process, `global` may not be a thing.

Comment: Indeed, but the answer specified they were talking about the Node.js module system.

Answer (score 1):

You're scope is already contained within the module - except for what you choose to export, so you don't really need the IIFE.

If you wanted it to work with an IIFE, you would have to attach the IIFE to `module.exports` rather than wrapping your IIFE around it. Something like...

```
module.exports = (function LinkedListInit() {   
    function LinkedList() {
        this.head;
    }        
    return new LinkedList();
// ...
```